# Unescaped string in attributes by Blazor

Tags: .net, security, encoding, blazor, xss

I am currently researching XSS possibilities and dangers with Blazor (Server).

Normally, Blazor does do an automatic output encoding of strings. I [have read](https://www.meziantou.net/rendering-raw-unescaped-html-in-blazor.htm) that, this can be avoided by using the [MarkupString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.markupstring) class.

This does work well for normal text outputs, but not if the variable is within an attribute. If this is my template

```
<div class="page @(myString)">
@(myString)
</div>

@code {
   MarkupString myString = new MarkupString("\" foo");
}
```

then the rendered output becomes

```html
<div class="page &quot; foo">
" foo
</div>
```

The first occurence of the MarkupString does get encoded, the second one not.

Can somebody explain to me this diverging behaviour? Is there some way to prevent the encoding in the first case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you write in a Razor file regarding the layout will be translated to calls to `RenderTreeBuilder`. This class has a method for `public void AddContent(int sequence, MarkupString markupContent)` and another for `public void AddContent(int sequence, object? textContent)`. For attribute, though, there is no specialist overload for the `MarkupString` class. Hence, you experienced that the same variable is encoded when used as an attribute, but not when used as content.

As a reference, have a look at the class https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/Rendering/RenderTreeBuilder.cs

Down from there, it goes very quickly, into the entrails of how Blazor is rendering. I'm not an expert in this field, but I didn't find any way to go around the default HTML encoding of attribute values.